# GCP Cloud Logging wont add trace to structured logs

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, logging, google-cloud-logging

I'm trying to make structured logging where the custom logs are connected to a trace from a Python service. This is the logging payload being sent to Cloud Logging

```
        logging_payload = {
        "time": "",
        "severity": "",
        "message": "",
        "custom_labels": {},
        "logging.googleapis.com/trace": "",
        "logging.googleapis.com/spanId": "",
        "logging.googleapis.com/labels": {
            "Custom-label1": ""
```

The log gets sent to the cloud logger as a jsonPayload with the python library 'google.cloud.logging'. The problem is that the entities "logging.googleapis.com/trace, logging.googleapis.com/spanId, logging.googleapis.com/labels" are completely removed by GCP Logging Agent, and not relocated to the top level in the logs, thus the logs are not connected to a tracing id.
What might be the cause of these fields getting removed completely?

Answer (score 1):

As per your JSON Payload you didn't mention the values which need to be given in the Payload format. For LOGEntry need to mention fields and its values as  below :

- logging.googleapis.com/labels : "logging.googleapis.com/labels":
  {"user_label_1":"value_1","user_label_2":"value_2"}
- logging.googleapis.com/spanId :
  "logging.googleapis.com/spanId":"000000000000004a"
- logging.googleapis.com/trace :
  "logging.googleapis.com/trace":"projects/my-projectid/traces/0679686673a"

Below is the sample example of log entry :

```
{
  "severity":"ERROR",
  "message":"There was an error in the application.",
  "httpRequest":{
    "requestMethod":"GET"
  },
  "times":"2020-10-12T07:20:50.52Z",
  "logging.googleapis.com/insertId":"42",
  "logging.googleapis.com/labels":{
    "user_label_1":"value_1",
    "user_label_2":"value_2"
  },
  "logging.googleapis.com/operation":{
    "id":"get_data",
    "producer":"github.com/MyProject/MyApplication",
     "first":"true"
  },
  "logging.googleapis.com/sourceLocation":{
    "file":"get_data.py",
    "line":"142",
    "function":"getData"
  },
  "logging.googleapis.com/spanId":"000000000000004a",
  "logging.googleapis.com/trace":"projects/my-projectid/traces/06796866738c859f2f19b7cfb3214824",
  "logging.googleapis.com/trace_sampled":false
}
```

Refer to this [doc1](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging#special-payload-fields) and [doc2](https://medium.com/google-cloud/structured-logging-in-google-cloud-61ee08898888) on how to Use the Logging agent.

Comment: I managed to fix it with the gcloud_logger.log_struct(jsonPayload, trace="traceid",ect) method instead